# PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json ignores top-level array?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to parse a JSON array with `ConvertFrom-Json` but it seems PowerShell is ignoring the array if it is on the top level.

For example, this unexpectedly returns count = 1:

```
'[{a:1},{b:2}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | measure
```

But when I put the JSON array inside an object it seems to be parsed as expected. This returns count = 2

```
('{list:[{a:1},{b:2}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json).list | measure
```

If `ConvertFrom-Json` does not work on JSON arrays, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'[{a:1},{b:2}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | measure`

What you've done is measure the number of objects returned by the pipeline.  The pipeline returns an array of 2 objects, not 2 objects.

if you want the number of things in the array you could do this:

`('[{a:1},{b:2}]' | ConvertFrom-Json).Count`

With the second example, PowerShell is unrolling list to get the items inside it (normal PowerShell pipeline behavior).

Comment: Yup. It's the same as doing `,@(1,2,3) | Measure-Object` versus `@(1,2,3) | Measure-Object`.

Comment: I disagree with the "PowerShell is unrolling list to get the items inside it (normal PowerShell pipeline behavior)" in that adding parentheses is not 'normal'. That's an extra step, and it's not what you'd expect parentheses to do in any other language. I don't even know how I would Google for the Microsoft documentation that explains this behavior of parentheses. It certainly isn't in the ConvertFrom-Json docs, though it really should be. Still, +1 for showing me the syntax.

Comment: Bacon Bits' leading comma is the same sort of arcane "how would I ever expect that" type of syntax behavior as the parentheses. These are hallmarks of bad language design.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple - PowerShell routinely unrolls arrays on the pipeline.  The parens weren't causing that, they were "undoing" that by collecting things together.